# Ocupo ejecutar un $.Confirm de jquery pero con parámetros

Tags: jquery

¿Cómo puedo agregarle parámetros al siguiente código?

```
 $("#complexConfirm").confirm({

            title:"<button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-circle'><i class='fa fa-check'></i></button>        Cambio de estatus...",
            text: 'Desea cambiar el status a ' + status + ' el requerimiento '+ registro,
            icon: 'fa fa-question-circle',
            animation: 'scale',
             modalOptionsBackdrop: 'static',
modalOptionsKeyboard: false,
            confirm: function(button) {
                button.fadeOut(2000).fadeIn(2000);
               location.reload();
            },
            cancel: function(button) {

                $.alert('La operación se ha <strong>Cancelado</strong>.');
            },
            confirmButton: "Aceptar",
            cancelButton: "Cancelar"
        });
```

Comment: Que para metros queires agregar y con que fin, ?

Comment: Tengo una tabla con registros, donde una columna tengo opciones para cambiar de status un registro. El código muestra un cuadro para confirmar la operación del cambio de "status" pero ocupo pasar un parámetro para identificar el registro. Los parámetros serían el id_status y el id_registro.

Comment: Hola Roberto! Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Para que te podamos ayudar, por favor crea un [mvce], con tu código HTML y JS en funcionamiento.

Comment: Roberto, no se entiende muy bien que es lo que necesitas. Estaria bien si nos lo explicas un poco mas detalladamente. Podria ser util, la tabla de la que hablas, como quieres pasarle los parámetros y a que quieres pasárselos.